# Get empty req.body when deployed on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a react app front end posting data to my server(use express) deployed on Heroku. Code works well when both client and server running on localhost, but when it's on Heroku, the req.body always gets empty object {}. 
Can anyone point out what's going wrong here? Thanks in advance :)

**React code:**

```
axios.post("/api", data, {headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" }})
```

**Express code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(
cors({origin: URL,credentials: true}));
app.post("/api", (req, res) => {const data = req.body; console.log(data);};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This run perfectly on my computer. The log and the response works just fine. Hope it helps. I think the problem could be you are sending a GET request instead of a POST request.

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors({origin: new URL('http://localhost:3000'), credentials: true})) // Add this 'new' keyword to URL

app.post("/api", (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body
    console.log(data)
    res.send(data) // Added this to allow request to end
})

// Added this part to start the server listen.
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port , () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port '+3000)
})
```

Comment: Problem solved by following your  "Add this 'new' keyword to URL", thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, you are welocome! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.